# Raise permutation to the power of 150

Tags: group-theory

Given the following permutation

(1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10)

Now I have to raise it to the power of 150, s0

((1 3 4 6 7)(2 5 9 8 10))^150 = (1 3 4 6 7)^150 (2 5 9 8 10)^150 =

As 5 (number of elements in every circle) divides 150, the solution should again be

= ( 1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10)

Is it really that easy or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: It is  that easy: the order of a cycle is its length.

Comment: Isn't the fifth power equal to the identity permutation, not the given permutation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the two permutations, let's call them $\sigma$ and $\tau$, are *disjoint* and hence *commute*, this warrants pulling the $150$ through: $(\sigma\tau)^{150}=\sigma^{150}\tau^{150}$, which in general is not true. The *order* of each of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is $5$ (the length of the cycle). Hence $\sigma$ and $\tau$ to the power of any multiple of $5$ will give you the identity. So the answer is $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why the answer you give is incorrect, I would recommend taking the permutation the the first 6 powers, i.e.

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^1 =$

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^2 =$

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^3 =$

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^4 =$

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^5 =$

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^6 =$

to give an intuition for how exponentiating permutations works. Given these solutions, you also relatively simply find

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^{10} = $

$((1 3 4 6 7) (2 5 9 8 10))^{15} = $

Etc.